# Registros en C - Array subscript is not an int

Tags: c

Estoy comenzando a ver el tema de "Resgistros" en C pero tengo un error y no sé que es lo que está mal declarado o si es otra cosa,el error, es "Array subscript is not an int" en la linea dentro al main, quisiera saber como solucionarlo gracias!

```
typedef struct DNI
{
    char nombre_apellido[MAX_CHAR];
}tDNI;

tDNI nuevoDni()
{
    tDNI aux;
    printf("Ingrese el Nombre y apellido\n");
    scanf("%f",&aux.nombre_apellido);
    return aux;
}

int main()
{
    tDNI vdnis[MAX_VECTOR];
    int opcion;
    int* cantDni = 0;
    do
    {
        menu();
        scanf("%d",&opcion);
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                vdnis[cantDni] = nuevoDni();
                cantDni++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error. Opcion no dispobible\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    while(opcion != 5);
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    printf("1.Ver listado\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás declarando a **cantDni** como un puntero, o sea lo estás declarando así:

```
int* cantDni = 0;
```

Cuando debería ser así:

```
int cantDni = 0;
```

O sea, sin el asterisco.

Comment: Aaaahh ahora si! Gracias!!